# Explain $\Bbb Q$ is a dense set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, education

This is approximately my explanation for **14-year-old students** in saying that $\Bbb Q$ is a dense set.

In contrast to the set $\Bbb N$ and the set $\Bbb Z$, between any two rationals another rational is always included, and thus we can say that between two rationals infinite rationals are included.

For example, let us put the numbers $0$ and $1$ on the straight line. Now let us denote on the line a rational number between $0$ and $1$, for example, their half.

Now we indicate on the line a rational number between $0$ and $\frac 12$, for example, their half. I will obtain the sequence $0, \frac 14, \frac 12$.
Now we indicate on the line a rational number between $0$ and $\frac 14$, for example, their half $\frac 18$.

Considering to always divide by $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ with $n\in\Bbb N$ the fraction $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ with the large $n$ the points in the subdivision will all accumulate toward $0$ (zero becomes an accumulation point).

For this reason we can say that the set $\Bbb Q$ is a DENSE set.

By this expression we mean an ordered set in which, given any INTERVAL, THERE IS AT LEAST ONE ELEMENT INSIDE it.

*Is there another easy explanation to give my students or is the one I have given enough?*

Comment: Seems like an intuitive explanation (assuming u kept the math notation to a minimum), maybe go more into the non examples

Comment: @bananapeel22 Thank you. Any response is welcome.

Comment: In your procedure you need to also insert between 1/2 and 1 for example. If only follow what you said it won't be dense, but only have a limit point at 0.

Comment: Teach them about the decimal representations of rational and irrational numbers. Then show that by truncating any irrational number anywhere you want, you get rational numbers arbitrarily close.

Comment: If you're only dealing with the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb Q$ (rather than the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R),$ which your (incomplete) argument suggests you're trying to do, then simply point out that the midpoint of two given rational numbers is a rational number (why?) that lies between the two given rational numbers. As for rationals lying between any two real numbers, you can argue by using examples to show how to select a terminating decimal (which will represent a rational number) between any two terminating and/or non-terminating decimal expansions.

Comment: Somehow I missed @John Douma's comment about truncating decimal expansions, which is essentially the same thing I was talking about at the end of my previous comment. However, there are two types of notions of "density" occurring here, one being in the sense of distance only (i.e. don't have to be between any two given points, just arbitrary close to any given point) and the other in the sense of order only (not necessarily arbitrarily close to any given point, but must be between any two given points). Appropriately truncating the larger of the two decimal expansions takes care of both.

Comment: @JohnDouma Any answer is welcome. I ask if you can put an answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Any answer is welcome. I not memorize the messages and I ask you to put a complete answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition: A [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) $S$ is [order-dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order)* [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if)

$$\forall x_{\in S} \forall y_{\in S} (x < y \to \exists z_{\in S} (x < z \land z < y))$$

That is, if $x < y$, there is some $z$ between them.

Theorem: $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense.

Proof: Let $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Suppose $x < y$. $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed under addition and division, so $z = \frac{x + y}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Furthermore,
\begin{align}
x
&= \frac{2x}{2} \\
&= \frac{x + x}{2} \\
&< \frac{x + y}{2} & x < y \\
&= z
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
z
&= \frac{x + y}{2} \\
&< \frac{y + y}{2} & x < y \\
&= \frac{2y}{2} \\
&= y
\end{align}
$\Box$

* Not to be confused with [topologically dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set).

Answer (score 3):

I would slightly modify your explanation by adding one preliminary step and one final step.

Step 1: Motivate the definition of "dense" which is jargon but students already have a sense of what it is.

Let $X$ be a collection of points that can be (totally) ordered: for all $x,y$ in $X$, either $x<y$ or $y<x$ or $x=y$. For example, $X$ may look like $$x_1<x_2<x_3,\qquad X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$$
or $$x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{999}<\cdots<x_{n}<y,\qquad X=\{y,x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$$
or $$x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{999}<\cdots<x_{n}<y<z,\qquad X=\{z,y,x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$$

Henceforth assume $X$ is an infinite collection.

Say $X$ is *dense* if for each $y$ in $X$, there exists an infinite sequence of points $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ such that the points $x_n$ never coincide with $y$ (i.e. $x_n\ne y$) and either
$$x_1<x_2<\cdots<y\qquad\text{i.e.}\qquad \begin{cases}m<n\Rightarrow x_m<x_n\\n=0,1,2,\ldots\Rightarrow(x_n<y)\end{cases}$$
OR
$$y<\cdots<x_2<x_1\qquad\text{i.e.}\qquad \begin{cases}m<n\Rightarrow x_n<x_m\\n=0,1,2,\ldots\Rightarrow(y<x_n)\end{cases}$$
I recommend having a chalkboard for this previous part, and I recommend saying "the 'x-sub-n'approach y either from the left or from the right." Also, for the children, please do not use logic notation such as $\wedge$ or $\exists$.

Step 2: [insert your explanation that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense]

Step 3: Remark that there is a simpler and <strike>equivalent</strike> stricter definition of dense-ness.

Say $X$ is *dense* if for all $x,y$ in $X$, if $x\ne y$, then there exists $z$ in $X$ such that either $x<z<y$ or $y<z<x$. [justify the equivalence with intuition learned from the explanation in Step 2]

Let the students ponder why this definition is "stricter" (I almost missed it entirely before logging off MSE, for example)

Comment: Thank you very much